# how to disable/enable etoolbox global command effect at different locations in a document?

Tags: sectioning, etoolbox

I am not able to figure how to do this, and I did look at the [etoolbox documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf)

The problem is simple to explain: I use etoolbox to append a `\clearpage` before any `\section` in a large document so that each section starts on a new page. (it is a book style document, but the MWE below is an article)

There are few sections that are small, and I want to tell etoolbox to not do this for the following section, and then tell it to start again after the section is finished.

How to do this? what is the etoolbox or Latex command for this?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%        
\usepackage{etoolbox}\preto\section{\clearpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[75]

\section{B}
\lipsum[75]

%do not add \clearpage here, how? 
\section{C}
\lipsum[75]

%now start adding \clearpage, it is ok
\section{D}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Texlive 2013, Linux mint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possibility is to create a switch and depending whether the switch is true or false execute the `\clearpage` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%        
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtoggle{clearpagebeforesection}

\preto{\section}{\iftoggle{clearpagebeforesection}{\clearpage}{}}

\begin{document}
\toggletrue{clearpagebeforesection}
\section{A}
\lipsum[75]

\section{B}
\lipsum[75]

%do not add \clearpage here, how? 
\togglefalse{clearpagebeforesection}
\section{C}
\lipsum[75]

%now start adding \clearpage, it is ok
\toggletrue{clearpagebeforesection}
\section{D}
\lipsum[75]

\section{E}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

One possibility is to create a command that locally (read *in group*) `relax`es `\clearpage`:

```
% locally disable clearpage
\newcommand{\specialsection}[1]{
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section{#1}
\endgroup
}
```

This way, `\clearpage` is set by default to all the sections in the document, but to the `\specialsection`s it doesn't apply.

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\section{\clearpage}

% locally disable clearpage
\newcommand{\specialsection}[1]{
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section{#1}
\endgroup
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[75]

\section{B}
\lipsum[75]

% we use the new command
\specialsection{C}
\lipsum[75]

\section{D}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```